# localhost do not load due to php code

Tags: php, sql, xampp, localhost

my xampp localhost was working well till i add this code to my php file

```
<?php while ($notification) {?>
<li>
<?php 
  echo $notification['notification'];
  ?>
  </li>
  <?php
} ?>
```

now the page is not loading or partially loading

here $notification is

```
$notification_sql= "SELECT id FROM notifications WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION['user']}'";

       $notification_query = mysqli_query($conn, $notification_sql);
      $notification = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notification_query);
```

Comment: probably a fatal error? nothing to see on screen ./ source of browser? Is error reporting ON? `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errrors', 1); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I begin I want to recommend you something: Avoid the use of the `while` statetements. Unless they are really needed - like in the exact way they are used in the PHP docs (and even then you can find alternatives) - they should be avoided all the time. I present the motive down under.

That said,... it's not `$notification['notification']`, but `$notification['id']`.

After you change it, you still remain with the issue: an ***infinite loop***. Because you are using a `while` loop without changing the state of the loop condition. E.g_ you are validating the `$notification` array for beeing existent. Because it exists all the time - it's state never beeing changed in the loop - then the iterations will be infinite in number. In order to avoid this dangerous (!!!) situation, you can use the following codes.

### Method 1:

Notice the difference: `$notification` is valid only for the period of a loop step. After each iteration `$notification` is newly created. And, when `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns `FALSE` on the (last + 1)-iteration step, then the `$notification` receives that value and, therefore, the loop ends.

```
<?php
$notification_sql = "SELECT id FROM notifications WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION['user']}'";

$notification_query = mysqli_query($conn, $notification_sql);

if ($notification_query) {
    while ($notification = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notification_query)) {
        ?>
        <li>
            <?php
            echo $notification['id'];
            ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }

    mysqli_free_result($notification_query);
}
```

?>

### Method 2:

Or, if you want to fetch the results in an array and to output its items later, then you can do it like this:

```
<?php
$notification_sql = "SELECT id FROM notifications WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION['user']}'";

$notification_query = mysqli_query($conn, $notification_sql);

$notifications = array();

if ($notification_query) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notification_query)) {
        $notifications[] = $row['id'];
    }

    mysqli_free_result($notification_query);
}

// OTHER STUFF AFTER FETCHING...
?>

<?php
// LOOPING AT A LATER TIME.
foreach ($notifications as $notificationId) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <?php
        echo $notificationId;
        ?>
    </li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

### Other recommendations:

- Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in order to avoid MySQL injection.
- Use [exception handling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) in order to catch all errors and handle them correspondingly. Especially when you run database operations.
- Use `PDO` instead of `mysqli`.

Here I have provided full code examples of prepared statements combined with exception handling (using `mysqli` library):

- [Can't insert info in a server, but i can as localhost (See EDIT 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989248/cant-insert-info-in-a-server-but-i-can-as-localhost/44315798#44315798)
- [Login using MySqli Prepared Statement (See solution 1 & 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200833/login-using-mysqli-prepared-statement/44235468#44235468)

Good luck.