# return multiple response data in one response

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

in my subjects table i have all student's classes by semester and month with each month's points

```
[
{
"id": "4", - this is the subject id
"userid": "1",
"name": "bio",
"semester": "3", - semester
"month": "5", - the month
"points": "652" - points of this class
"time": "2017-06-18 22:45:04"
},
{
"id": "3", - this is the subject id
"userid": "1",
"name": "math",
"semester": "3", - semester
"month": "4", - the month
"points": "33" - points of this class
"time": "2017-05-15 22:45:04"
},
{
"id": "2", - this is the subject id
"userid": "1",
"name": "chem",
"semester": "1", - semester
"month": "3", - the month
"points": "22" - points of this class
"time": "2017-04-11 22:45:04"
},
{
"id": "1", - this is the subject id
"userid": "1",
"name": "phy",
"semester": "1", - semester
"month": "2", - the month
"points": "10" - points of this class
"time": "2017-02-10 22:45:04"
}
]
```

**this is what i tried**

```
$sql = "SELECT users.id userid,users.name username,subjects.id subjectsid, subjects.name subjectname, subjects.points activepts FROM tbusers AS users INNER JOIN tbsubjects AS subjects ON users.id = subjects.userid WHERE users.id = '$userid' ORDER BY subjects.time DESC";

try {
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$db = null;

if(empty($user)) {
    $response->getBody()->write
    ('
    {
        "error":
        {
            "message":"Invalid"
        }
    }');
} else {
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($user));
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {}
```

the current output i am getting from my query is multiple responses for each because of `fetchAll` i could just change it to `fetch` but it won't get the other data

```
[
{
"userid": "1",
"username": "joe",
"subjectid": "4",
"subjectname": "bio",
"activepts": "652"
},
"userid": "1",
"username": "joe",
"subjectid": "3",
"subjectname": "math",
"activepts": "33"
},
"userid": "1",
"username": "joe",
"subjectid": "2",
"subjectname": "chem",
"activepts": "22"
},
"userid": "1",
"username": "joe",
"subjectid": "1",
"subjectname": "phy",
"activepts": "10"
}
]
```

my question is how can i merge them into one response and return the below data in the expected output (i have added a little description of each field to explain it)

**expected output**

```
[
{
"userid": "1", - from users table
"username": "joe",  - from users table 
"subjectsid": "1", - first subject id for the student in this case the one for phy
"subjectname": "bio", - current subject name 
"activepts": "652", - points of current month
"totalpts": "717", - total points of all subjects for this student
"sem1": "32", - total points of all subjects for this student of semester 1
"sem2": "0", - total points of all subjects for this student of semester 2
"sem3": "685", - total points of all subjects for this student of semester 3
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, you want to fetch the subjects, not the students. So, I inverted the FROM and LEFT JOIN. So, when you want a list of subjects, you are starting with SELECT ... FROM subjects. Then, if you need other details to each subject (like username, etc), you apply LEFT JOIN, which means: JOIN all the needed details (username, etc) to each record of the LEFT table, e.g. of the main table (in you case is table "subjects").

Good luck!

```
<?php

try {
    $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter();

    $connection = $dbAdapter->connect();

    /*
     * I renamed user id variable (from $userId to $userid1) in order to show you that you can 
     * provide more users if you wish. Then you just have to extend 
     * the WHERE clause in the sql statement and the bindings array.
     */
    $userid1 = 1;

    /*
     * The sql statement - it will be prepared.
     * 
     * ======================================================
     * I'm not sure about the following fields - because you
     * didn't provide proper selection criteria for them:
     * 
     * 1) "subjectsid":  "1", - first subject id for the student in this case the one for phy
     * 2) "subjectname": "bio", - current subject name 
     * ======================================================
     */
    $sql = 'SELECT 
                subjects.userid,
                users.name AS username,
                (
                    SELECT id 
                    FROM tbsubjects 
                    WHERE userid = subjects.userid 
                    ORDER BY id ASC 
                    LIMIT 1
                ) AS subjectsid,
                (
                    SELECT name 
                    FROM tbsubjects 
                    WHERE 
                        userid = subjects.userid 
                        ORDER BY time DESC
                        LIMIT 1
                ) AS subjectname,
                (
                    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(points), 0) 
                    FROM tbsubjects 
                    WHERE 
                        userid = subjects.userid 
                        AND month = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%c")
                ) AS activepts,
                IFNULL(SUM(subjects.points), 0) AS totalpts,
                (
                    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(points), 0) 
                    FROM tbsubjects 
                    WHERE 
                        userid = subjects.userid 
                        AND semester = 1
                ) AS sem1,
                (
                    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(points), 0) 
                    FROM tbsubjects 
                    WHERE 
                        userid = subjects.userid 
                        AND semester = 2
                ) AS sem2,
                (
                    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(points), 0) 
                    FROM tbsubjects 
                    WHERE 
                        userid = subjects.userid 
                        AND semester = 3
                ) AS sem3 
            FROM 
                tbsubjects AS subjects 
                LEFT JOIN tbusers AS users ON users.id = subjects.userid 
            WHERE subjects.userid = :userid1 
            GROUP BY subjects.userid 
            ORDER BY subjects.time DESC';

    /*
     * The input parameters list for the prepared sql statement.
     */
    $bindings = array(
        ':userid1' => $userid1,
    );

    /*
     * Prepare and validate the sql statement.
     * 
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() 
     * returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling settings).
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

    if (!$statement) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('The sql statement could not be prepared!');
    }

    /*
     * Bind the input parameters to the prepared statement.
     * 
     * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), when using PDOStatement::bindParam() the variable 
     * is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that 
     * PDOStatement::execute() is called.
     * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    foreach ($bindings as $key => $value) {
        $bound = $statement->bindValue(
                getInputParameterName($key)
                , $value
                , getInputParameterDataType($value)
        );

        if (!$bound) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('An input parameter can not be bound!');
        }
    }

    /*
     * Execute the prepared statement.
     * 
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------
     * PDOStatement::execute returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    $executed = $statement->execute();

    if (!$executed) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('The prepared statement could not be executed!');
    }

    /*
     * Fetch users list - array of objects.
     */
    $users = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if ($users === FALSE) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('Fetching users list failed!');
    }

    /*
     * Close connection.
     */
    $connection = NULL;

    /*
     * Handle results.
     */
    if (empty($users)) {
        $response->getBody()->write(
            '{
                "error": {
                    "message":"Invalid"
                }
            }'
        );
    } else {
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($users));
    }
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    // $logger->log($exc);
    exit();
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    // $logger->log($exc);
    exit();
}

/**
 * Get the name of an input parameter by its key in the bindings array.
 *  
 * @param int|string $key The key of the input parameter in the bindings array.
 * @return int|string The name of the input parameter.
 */
function getInputParameterName($key) {
    return is_int($key) ? ($key + 1) : (':' . ltrim($key, ':'));
}

/**
 * Get the PDO::PARAM_* constant, e.g the data type of an input parameter, by its value.
 *  
 * @param mixed $value Value of the input parameter.
 * @return int The PDO::PARAM_* constant.
 */
function getInputParameterDataType($value) {
    $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    if (is_int($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    }
    return $dataType;
}
```

---

### EDIT:

For my projects I developed a DbAdapter class. The method names are self-explanatory. So, no more spagetti code inside each web page :-) But just:

- the sql statement,
- the bindings array,
- the call to the corresponding method in the db adapter and
- the disconnect-from-db line

The solution to your question would look like this:

```
<?php

//***********************************************************************************
// Put this in a php file (like db.php) to include whereever you need db data access.
//***********************************************************************************
//
// Db configs.
define('DB_HOST', '...');
define('DB_PORT', 3306);
define('DB_DBNAME', '...');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_USERNAME', '...');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '...');
define('DB_DRIVER_NAME', 'mysql');

// Create db adapter.
$dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(DB_HOST, DB_DBNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_PORT, DB_CHARSET);

//***********************************************************************************

$userid1 = 1;

// Sql statement.
$sql = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE subjects.userid = :userid1 GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ...';

// Input parameters.
$bindings = array(
    ':userid1' => $userid1,
);

// Fetch users.
$users = $dbAdapter->fetchAll($sql, $bindings);

// Disconnect from db.
$dbAdapter->disconnect();

/*
 * Handle results.
 */
if (empty($users)) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

The adapter methods to call are the `public` ones:

- **connect**: Connects to the database, e.g. creates a PDO instance, e.g
  creates a db connection.
- **disconnect**: Disconnects from the database.
- **fetchAll**: Fetches more records at once. Returns an array of arrays. So, each element is an array corresponding to a db record.
- **fetchOne**: Fetches only one record.
- **fetchColumn**: Fetches a column value.
- **update**: Performs an UPDATE query. Returns the number of affected rows.
- **delete**: Performs a DELETE query. Returns the number of affected rows.
- **insert**: Performs an INSERT query. Returns the last insert id.
- **getLastInsertId**: Returns the last insert id after an INSERT operation is performed.

That's all :-)

```
<?php

/*
 * Database adapter.
 */

/**
 * Database adapter.
 */
class DbAdapter {

    /**
     * Connection configs.
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    private $connectionConfigs;

    /**
     * Database connection.
     * 
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * PDO statement.
     * 
     * @var PDOStatement
     */
    private $statement;

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $host [optional] Host.
     * @param string $dbname [optional] Database name.
     * @param string $username [optional] User name.
     * @param string $password [optional] Password.
     * @param string $port [optional] Port.
     * @param string $charset [optional] Character set.
     * @param string $driverName [optional] Driver name.
     * @param array $driverOptions [optional] Driver options.
     * @return string DSN string.
     */
    public function __construct($host = '', $dbname = ''
    , $username = '', $password = '', $port = 3306, $charset = 'utf8', $driverName = 'mysql'
    , $driverOptions = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
    )) {
        $this->setConnectionConfigs(array(
            'host' => $host,
            'dbname' => $dbname,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'port' => $port,
            'charset' => $charset,
            'driverName' => $driverName,
            'driverOptions' => $driverOptions,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Connect to db, e.g. create a PDO instance.
     * 
     * @return $this
     * @throws PDOException
     */
    public function connect() {
        if (!isset($this->connection) || !$this->connection) {
            try {
                $this->connection = new PDO(
                        $this->createDsn(
                                $this->connectionConfigs['host']
                                , $this->connectionConfigs['dbname']
                                , $this->connectionConfigs['port']
                                , $this->connectionConfigs['charset']
                                , $this->connectionConfigs['driverName']
                        )
                        , $this->connectionConfigs['username']
                        , $this->connectionConfigs['password']
                        , $this->connectionConfigs['driverOptions']
                );
            } catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
                echo $pdoException->getMessage();
                exit();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect from db.
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function disconnect() {
        $this->connection = NULL;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Create a DSN string.
     * 
     * @param string $host Host.
     * @param string $dbname Database name.
     * @param string $port Port.
     * @param string $charset Character set.
     * @param string $driverName Driver name.
     * @return string DSN string.
     */
    private function createDsn($host, $dbname, $port, $charset, $driverName) {
        switch ($driverName) {
            default: // mysql
                $dsn = sprintf('%s:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s'
                        , $driverName
                        , $host
                        , $port
                        , $dbname
                        , $charset
                );
                break;
        }

        return $dsn;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch data by executing a SELECT sql statement.
     * 
     * @param string $sql Sql statement.
     * @param array $bindings [optional] Input parameters.
     * @param integer $fetchMode [optional] Fetch mode for a PDO statement.
     *  Must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants.
     * @param mixed $fetchArgument [optional] Fetch argument for a PDO statement.
     * @param array $fetchConstructorArguments [optional] Constructor arguments for a PDO statement 
     *  when fetch mode is PDO::FETCH_CLASS.
     * @return array An array containing the rows in the result set, or FALSE on failure.
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException
     */
    public function fetchAll($sql, array $bindings = array(), $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, $fetchArgument = NULL, array $fetchConstructorArguments = array()) {
        $this
                ->prepareStatement($sql)
                ->bindInputParameters($bindings)
                ->executePreparedStatement()
        ;

        try {
            if (isset($fetchArgument)) {
                $data = $this->getStatement()->fetchAll($fetchMode, $fetchArgument, $fetchConstructorArguments);
            } else {
                $data = $this->getStatement()->fetchAll($fetchMode);
            }

            if ($data === FALSE) {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException('Fetching data failed!');
            }

            return $data;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            echo $exception->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetch the next row from the result set by executing a SELECT sql statement.
     * The fetch mode property determines how PDO returns the row.
     * 
     * @param string $sql Sql statement.
     * @param array $bindings [optional] Input parameters.
     * @param integer $fetchMode [optional] Fetch mode for a PDO statement.
     *  Must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants.
     * @param integer $fetchCursorOrientation [optional] For a PDOStatement object representing 
     *  a scrollable cursor, this value determines which row will be returned to the caller.
     * @param integer $fetchCursorOffset [optional] The absolute number of the row in the result 
     *  set, or the row relative to the cursor position before PDOStatement::fetch() was called.
     * @return array An array containing the next row in the result set, or FALSE on failure.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function fetchOne($sql, array $bindings = array(), $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, $fetchCursorOrientation = PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT, $fetchCursorOffset = 0) {
        $this
                ->prepareStatement($sql)
                ->bindInputParameters($bindings)
                ->executePreparedStatement()
        ;

        try {
            /*
             * =========================================================
             * NB:
             * =========================================================
             * PDOStatement::fetch returns FALSE not only on failure,
             * but ALSO when no record is found! This is a BUG. That's
             * why I made the try-catch block: maybe on failure will
             * throw an exception.
             * 
             * Instead, PDOStatement::fetchAll returns FALSE on failure,
             * but an empty array if no record is found. This is the
             * correct behaviour.
             * =========================================================
             */
            $data = $this->getStatement()->fetch($fetchMode, $fetchCursorOrientation, $fetchCursorOffset);

            return $data;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            echo $exception->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a single column from the next row of a result set 
     * or FALSE if there are no more rows.
     * 
     * =================================================================
     * Note:
     * -----
     * PDOStatement::fetchColumn() should not be used to retrieve 
     * boolean columns, as it is impossible to distinguish a value 
     * of FALSE from there being no more rows to retrieve.
     * Use PDOStatement::fetch() instead.
     * 
     * Warning:
     * --------
     * There is no way to return another column from the same row if you
     * use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve data.
     * =================================================================
     * 
     * @param string $sql Sql statement.
     * @param array $bindings [optional] Input parameters.
     * @param integer $columnNumber [optional] 0-indexed number of the 
     *  column you wish to retrieve from the row. If no value is supplied, 
     *  PDOStatement::fetchColumn() fetches the first column.
     * @return mixed A single column from the next row of a result set 
     *  or FALSE if there are no more rows.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function fetchColumn($sql, array $bindings = array(), $columnNumber = 0) {
        $this
                ->prepareStatement($sql)
                ->bindInputParameters($bindings)
                ->executePreparedStatement()
        ;

        try {
            return $this->getStatement()->fetchColumn($columnNumber);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            echo $exception->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store data by executing an INSERT sql statement.
     * 
     * @param string $sql Sql statement.
     * @param array $bindings [optional] Input parameters.
     * @return int Last insert id.
     */
    public function insert($sql, array $bindings = array()) {
        $this
                ->prepareStatement($sql)
                ->bindInputParameters($bindings)
                ->executePreparedStatement()
        ;

        return $this->getLastInsertId();
    }

    /**
     * Update data by executing an UPDATE sql statement.
     * 
     * @param string $sql Sql statement.
     * @param array $bindings [optional] Input parameters.
     * @return int Number of affected rows.
     */
    public function update($sql, array $bindings = array()) {
        $this
                ->prepareStatement($sql)
                ->bindInputParameters($bindings)
                ->executePreparedStatement()
        ;

        return $this->getStatement()->rowCount();
    }

    /**
     * Delete data by executing a DELETE sql statement.
     * 
     * @param string $sql Sql statement.
     * @param array $bindings [optional] Input parameters.
     * @return int Number of affected rows.
     */
    public function delete($sql, array $bindings = array()) {
        $this
                ->prepareStatement($sql)
                ->bindInputParameters($bindings)
                ->executePreparedStatement()
        ;

        return $this->getStatement()->rowCount();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and validate an sql statement.
     * 
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     * If the database server cannot successfully prepare 
     * the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits 
     * PDOException (depending on error handling settings).
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     * 
     * @param string $sql Sql statement.
     * @return $this
     * @throws PDOException
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException
     */
    private function prepareStatement($sql) {
        $this->connect();
        try {
            $statement = $this->getConnection()->prepare($sql);

            if (!$statement) {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException('The sql statement can not be prepared!');
            }

            $this->setStatement($statement);
        } catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
            echo $pdoException->getMessage();
            exit();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            echo $exception->getMessage();
            exit();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Bind the input parameters to a prepared PDO statement.
     * 
     * @param array $bindings Input parameters.
     * @return $this
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException
     */
    private function bindInputParameters($bindings) {
        foreach ($bindings as $key => $value) {
            try {
                $bound = $this->getStatement()->bindValue(
                        $this->getInputParameterName($key)
                        , $value
                        , $this->getInputParameterDataType($value)
                );

                if (!$bound) {
                    throw new UnexpectedValueException('A value can not be bound!');
                }
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
                echo $exception->getMessage();
                exit();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the name of an input parameter by its key in the bindings array.
     *  
     * @param int|string $key The key of the input parameter in the bindings array.
     * @return int|string The name of the input parameter.
     */
    private function getInputParameterName($key) {
        return is_int($key) ? ($key + 1) : (':' . ltrim($key, ':'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the PDO::PARAM_* constant, e.g the data type of an input parameter, by its value.
     *  
     * @param mixed $value Value of the input parameter.
     * @return int The PDO::PARAM_* constant.
     */
    private function getInputParameterDataType($value) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        if (is_int($value)) {
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
        } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        }
        return $dataType;
    }

    /**
     * Execute a prepared PDO statement.
     * 
     * @return $this
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException
     */
    private function executePreparedStatement() {
        try {
            if (!$this->getStatement()->execute()) {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException('The statement can not be executed!');
            }
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            echo $exception->getMessage();
            exit();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the ID of the last inserted row or of the sequence value.
     * 
     * @param string $sequenceObjectName [optional] Name of the sequence object 
     *  from which the ID should be returned.
     * @return string The ID of the last row, or the last value retrieved from the specified 
     *  sequence object, or an error IM001 SQLSTATE If the PDO driver does not support this.
     * @throws PDOException
     */
    public function getLastInsertId($sequenceObjectName = NULL) {
        $this->connect();
        try {
            return $this->getConnection()->lastInsertId($sequenceObjectName);
        } catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
            echo $pdoException->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get connection configs.
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConnectionConfigs() {
        return $this->connectionConfigs;
    }

    /**
     * Set connection configs.
     * 
     * @param array $connectionConfigs Connection configs.
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setConnectionConfigs($connectionConfigs) {
        $this->connectionConfigs = $connectionConfigs;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get database connection.
     * 
     * @return PDO Database connection.
     */
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->connection;
    }

    /**
     * Set database connection.
     * 
     * @param PDO $connection Database connection.
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setConnection(PDO $connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get PDO statement.
     * 
     * @return PDOStatement
     */
    public function getStatement() {
        return $this->statement;
    }

    /**
     * Set PDO statement.
     * 
     * @param PDOStatement $statement PDO statement.
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStatement(PDOStatement $statement) {
        $this->statement = $statement;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: wow, just finished reading your comments, thank you for all of your comments and feedback, taught me a lot, your answer deserves a reward seriously! still need to test it though ;) give me few min, really appreciate your help buddy

Comment: @mirvatJ Well, I'm glad it was of help for you. Take your time. I'm still here for about 30 minutes in case you have any questions.

Comment: @mirvatJ I just tested it. For all columns - except the two (`subjectsid` & `subjectname`) about which I told you in the comments that I'm not sure - it seems that the proper results are outputed. I need from you the proper criterias for the two columns and the values of `time` column for each subject. I speak only about data in your presented example, ok?

Comment: @mirvatJ I just tested it with two users: `SELECT ... WHERE subjects.userid = 1 OR subjects.userid = 2`. It works good.

Comment: oh subject name is returned null, and subjectid is returning the newest where i want the oldest, updated my question to add the subject time and explained which one is subject id

Comment: fixed it, changed the subject id to `ASC` and changed the name to `order by time` and `limit 1`

Comment: @mirvatJ Yep, that's the way for subjectsid and subjectname, my friend! Good luck further. Bye

Comment: @mirvatJ I added something pretty cool for you (see the "EDIT" in my answer). But I had to delete the early comments with my advices for you, because the editor allows only 30000 characters. I'll save them and give you later, somehow, if you want them. Bye

Comment: wow :D that's a pretty impressive way to do it, I am learning a lot from you, thank you so much :)

Comment: @mirvatJ You are welcome. Actually, I gave the class to you because it passed all my tests in the last 3 months and yesterday I've documented myself again to see if I still have to change something in it. Only one more fundamental function is to be added (`query`) - to run db specific queries like `ALTER TABLE xyz`, etc. Otherwise, it is in the final state. From this point on it can be further extended with a lot new, more specific functions regarding, for example, reading db info vars or running a diversity of db specific queries. But the core of it - the CRUD operations - work very good. Bye