# PDO prepared statement with prepared sub-queries

Tags: php, sql, pdo, subquery, prepared-statement

There is a complex query that is prepared in different methods. Here is a pseudo-code (not actual code) : It would prepare a query in one method, then prepare a sub-query in another method.

The idea is that other methods could add some other query parts, adding some conditions, and potentially some joins to other table. And all sub-queries would be prepared in their method.

And finally, the resulting query would be executed in the original method.

```
class{//pseudo code

public function getData($name,$club){
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
  $stm1 = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE quote=?');
  $stm1 = $pdo->prepare('1');

  $stm2 = $this->getQueryPart();
  $stm1->statementBind($stm2);
  $stm1->execute();

  return $query;
}
protected function getQueryPart(){
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
  $pdo->prepare('AND email = ? AND status=?', ['email@foobar.com','1']);
  return $pdo;
}
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error in the first query there. And it doesn't sound very efficient to create a new connection in each function, why not just pass it as an argument?

Comment: And you can't chain queries like that, `prepare()` takes a single querystring, you can't add conditions to it by calling it like that. The final querystirng is what should be passed to `prepare()`.

Comment: @Qirel, it is stated not once, but _thrice_ that it's a pseudo code - and you cannot expect pseudo code to run, as it's not actually some proper code. Let alone syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using just PDO. You'll have to create a query builder class (or use one of the many existing ones out there) that **wraps around PDO** that will hold all of the query's properties, and build the full query in one go just before you execute it.

Here's a basic example of how this would work:

```
class Query {
    private $select;
    private $from;
    private $where = [];

    /**
     * Defines the column list (SELECT {$columns})
     *
     * @param string $columns
     * @return this
     */
    public function select($columns) {
        $this->select = $columns;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Defines the table to select from (SELECT * FROM {$table})
     *
     * @param string $table
     * @return this
     */
    public function from($table) {
        $this->from = $table;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * List of conditions to AND (key = column, value = value)
     * e.g. $query->where(['name' => 'bob'])
     *
     * @param mixed[string] $conditions
     * @return $this
     */
    public function where(array $conditions) {
        $this->where = $conditions;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Adds an AND condition
     *
     * @param string $column
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return this
     */
    public function where_and($column, $value) {
        $this->where[$column] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Builds and executes the query, returning a PDOStatement
     *
     * @return PDOStatement
     */
    public function execute() {
        $query = sprintf(
            'SELECT %s FROM %s',
            $this->select,
            $this->from
        );

        $placeholders = array();

        if (!empty($this->where)) {
            $query .= ' WHERE ';

            $index = 0;
            foreach ($this->where as $column => $value) {
                if ($index > 0) {
                    $query .= ' AND ';
                }

                $query .= sprintf('`%s`', $column);

                if ($value === null) {
                    $query .= ' IS NULL';
                } else {
                    $placeholder = sprintf(':placeholder_%d', $index);

                    $query .= ' = ' . $placeholder;
                    $placeholders[$placeholder] = $value;
                }

                $index++;
            }
        }

        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($placeholders);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

With this class you could, for example, do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public function getData($name, $club) {
        $query = new Query();
        $query->select('name')
              ->from('users')
              ->where(['quote' => '1']);

        $this->getQueryPart($query);
        $result = $query->execute();

        return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    protected function getQueryPart($query) {
        $query->where_and('email', 'email@foobar.com')
              ->where_and('status', 1);
    }
}
```

See here for an example that doesn't actually execute the query, but prints the query and placeholders it would execute: https://3v4l.org/iKu2K

Note that this is a very basic example, just to give you an idea of how you could go about doing something like this. In a real-world scenario, you would probably want to expand this with the capability for `OR`-conditions as well as `LIKE` and `!=` checks and maybe even grouping conditions so you could do something like `WHERE a = 1 AND (b = 2 OR c = 5)`. Not to mention adding support for `JOIN`, `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` and other fancy things.

Comment: Good answer! Just a note, though: The _prepare > bind > execute > fetch_ workflow - including validations and exception handling - is the task of a database adapter class. E.g the query builder is only responsible with constructing the sql statement. Here an example of [a DbAdapter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014772/return-multiple-response-data-in-one-response/46018999#46018999) of mine (the EDIT part), if it's of interest for you.